# Identity using SendGrid v3 to send transactional template as confirmation email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm new to asp.net mvc Identity and SendGrid but would really like to use the functionality of both of them.

I would like to let the user sign up using identity registration form and then use SendGrid v3 to send a template (built in my SendGrid account) as the account registration confirmation email. I've created a Transactional template and have an Api Key.

I have enabled email confirmation in identity:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

I have then set up my sendGrid apiKey and account credentials in the app settings of my web.config so I can use them in my code.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SendGridUsername" value="xxxxxxx" />
  <add key="SendGridPassword" value="xxxxxxx" />
  <add key="SendGridApiKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</appSettings>
```

I have added this to my EmailService in the IdentityConfig.cs but i'm stuck on where to go from here:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email. 
        var apiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"];
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("me@us.com", "Me");
        var subject = message.Subject;
        var to = new EmailAddress(message.Destination);
        var email = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, "", message.Body);
        await client.SendEmailAsync(email);
    }
}
```

I've also read the following but cannot understand where to implement it:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/smtpapi.html

```
{
  "filters": {
    "templates": {
      "settings": {
        "enable": 1,
         "template_id": "5997fcf6-2b9f-484d-acd5-7e9a99f0dc1f"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Any help on this would be awesome as i'm just not sure where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone answer this? There seems to be no code examples out there - i've been looking for days!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send Transactional Templates in your emails using this code below:

```
        var apiKey = AppConstants.JuketserSendGridKey;
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("admin@jukester.com", "Jukester"));
        //msg.SetSubject("I'm replacing the subject tag");
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(model.EmailTo));
        //msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, "I'm replacing the <strong>body tag</strong>");
        msg.SetTemplateId("Your TemplateId here");

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        var status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

> Edit For Your Other question:

For Email confirmation scenario, you will have to send email to the registered email when a user signs up. Create a verification token and save it in database. That email will contain some link or a button in it. This link or button will have that verification token with it. Once user clicks that link/button, a webapi or an action method will be called in the project, there you will verify the verification code and then update the status of EmailConfirmed in the database.

Following are some code snippets that i have done, they might be of help to you.

The following code creates a verification code and updates the user record in database.

```
var encryptedToken = Utility.Crypt(user.Email);
var updateStatus = await UpdateVerificationCode(userToAdd, encryptedToken);
```

The following then passes this verification code to the data that needs to be sent in the email. "paramList" is a list of data.

```
if (updateStatus)
{
    paramList.Add(encryptedToken);
    var emailModel = Utility.CreateEmailModel(user.Email, paramList, AppConstants.RegistrationTemplateId, (int)EmailType.Register);
    await Helper.SendEmail(emailModel);

}
```

Now this code, will be attached in the link or button in the email sent to user for email verification. When user clicks that link/button then following web api action method for email verification is called.

```
public async Task<GenericResponse> ConfirmEmail(SetPasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        var response = new GenericResponse();
        if (model != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _aspNetUserService.GetByEmail(model.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.VerificationCode))
                    {
                        //if time difference is less than 5 minutes then proceed
                        var originalKey = Utility.Decrypt(model.VerificationCode);
                        if (user.Email == originalKey)
                        {
                            var emailConfirmationCode = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, emailConfirmationCode);
                            if (result.Succeeded)
                            {
                                var status = await _aspNetUserService.ResetVerificationCode(model.Email);
                                if (status)
                                {
                                    response.Message = AppConstants.EmailConfirmed;
                                    response.IsSuccess = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                response.Message = AppConstants.Error;
                                response.IsSuccess = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response.Message = AppConstants.InvalidVerificationCode;
                            response.IsSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.Message = AppConstants.InvalidVerificationCode;
                        response.IsSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response.Message = AppConstants.NoUserFound;
                    response.IsSuccess = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //response.Message = AppConstants.Error;
                response.Message = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        return response;
    }
```

You can take a look at it, and use it if it helps your needs. Thanks

Comment: But how can I confirm the registration and set the ApplicationUser EmailConfirmed boolean to true in my db?